# Pending Changes across projects seen in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Is there a VS setting that limits the pending changes I see to those of the current project? I have VS 2010 and when I attempt to view all pending changes, the list includes changes from other solutions.

Comment: Yes, there is an option, but you can also create Workspaces http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181383.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a button in the button bar of the "Pending Changes" window that limits the listed changes to the current *solution*.  Be careful using this, though, because sometimes there is stuff that probably belongs in source control but isn't actually part of the solution.